# Adding license file for an assembly in an ASP.Net project

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis-7, .net-assembly

I have an xml license file that needs to be deployed in the same directory as the assembly that references it is located.

I had assumed the BIN folder was the correct location.  However what is happening is that ASP.Net is copying the assembly to a folder similar to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\swsscriptstest\ef2666d0\23e85c28\assembly\dl3\9353205e\6605f3df_cd85cb01. Once IIS cleans up after itself, these files are deleted.

Since it's an XML and not an assembly file, I could not use  to the config.

I have also tried to add the file as an "embedded resource" with no luck.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: based on what Chris is saying, i am contacting the publisher of the DLL and see if there is some type of workaround... the xml file is pretty useless, but i am going to see if theres a way to configure the dll to look for this file elsewhere instead of the assembly.

Comment: Since every library has their own specifics please mention the name of the component. Otherwise the answers are not much of a help for others.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the XML into your solution and set the Copy to Output Directory to Copy always.

Comment: i had tried this and even tried as an "embedded resource"... I dont think it copies it to the assembly folder upon execution since i believe this method only copies directly to the bin/output directory.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with the xml file? If you're reading/writing to it in your app, the best place to put it is in ~/App_Data. You can get the full path at runtime by using `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/nameOfYourXmlFile.xml")`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx

Comment: One of the DLLs im using is referencing it as kind of a "license file."  It just says my name is. But the DLL needs it as part of the assembly. I have tried the App_data, the App_GlobalResources and the App_local resources, all with no luck...

Comment: In that case, go with @JeremySpouken's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Are you the publisher?

If so, then it sounds like you've code things completely wrong.

If it's config info, it belongs in the config file this way any app developer can deal with it on a normal level.

If it's not, then put it in the app_data folder.  That is a special folder designed for this purpose.

Point is, you cannot know where the assembly is executing from.  It might be gac'd, in the bin folder, or optimized into some other directory.

---

**Another option:**

If the assembly you have has an installer, run that on the web server.  This will most likely copy the assembly to the GAC along with the appropriate license file.

If it doesn't have an installer, try placing the assembly in the GAC.  Then figure out where windows actually stored it and copy the license file there.

Comment: no i am not the publisher. The documentation states the file must lie in the same deployed bin as the dll. I can make a console app and it works properly, but once i create it in asp, the xml file doesnt get built into the same location the assembly executes. I will try the app_data folder solution now

Comment: @Andy Danger Gagne: If Jeremy's answer doesn't work then I'd say contact the original publisher.  Whatever they did is not web friendly and you might need to get them to make some changes.